# ed is not working when looping through file- shell scriping

Tags: shell, sed, ed

```
#!/bin/bash
filename='urls.txt'
old_url="test"
while read line
do
  new_url=$line
  echo "New URL  is "$new_url
  echo -e '%s/'"$new_url"'/'"$old_url"'/g\nw' |ed ca-sample.conf
  old_url=$new_url
  echo ""
  echo "Old URL  is "$old_url
  sleep 60
done < $filename
exit
```

I am looping through urls.txt to read the lines one by one to replace the old url with the new one.
This command (echo -e '%s/'"$new_url"'/'"$old_url"'/g\nw' |ed ca-sample.conf) is working fine in 
command line (I have set the new_url and old_url as env variables "export new_url="New" and "export 
old_url="Old") but when I put this command in While loop it is not working.

Comment: Now try in command line with `export new_url="http://some_real_url/with_some_real_path"`

Comment: Using a [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) instead of piping from echo makes for much more readable ed scripting, btw.

Comment: @KamilCuk It is not working in command line when I give the real url in. I'm new to shell scripting. What does the command do actually? Could you please help me with this?

Comment: @Master, please do let us know sample input and sample expected output in your post which will provide us clear picture of your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Repeatedly editing a file in a loop is horribly inefficient. You probably want something like

```
awk -v old_url="test" '{ print "s%" old_url "%" $0 "%g"; old_url = $0 }' urls.txt |
tac |
sed -i~ - ca-sample.conf
```

Your `sed` might not accept a script on standard input; maybe store the generated script in a temporary file and pass that instead of `-`.

I put in the `tac` so that the new URL will not immediately be replaced with a newer one still.  Depending on what your data looks like and what you are actually trying to accomplish, this could be completely wrong, and/or require additional tweaks (regex anchors, for one thing?)

The verbose printing and the long `sleep` seem more distracting than helpful, though I suppose you could hack them back in if you really wanted to.  Also pay attention to the quoting -- you are quoting literal text (which doesn't need quoting) and leaving variables outside quotes (which is precisely what should crucially be *inside* quotes, for the quotes to be useful at all).